# SQLite iPhone SQL Select crashes application

Tags: iphone, sqlite, select

For some reason, my application fails at "NSAssert1(0, @"Error while looping search view. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));"
The SQL Statement is OK, because I used the same statement, when I open the database.
I don't get any useful errors :-(

I'm quite new to this, but not a total stranger
What am I doing wrong ?

Please note I have taken out the "strSearch" to be sure this is not the error.

```
- (void)searchComponents:(NSString *)strSearch {

    NSString *qry;

    qry = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ID, ON_SAP, SAP_PART, SAP_DESC, MOQ FROM HONEYWELL WHERE SAP_PART LIKE '%ZX%' ORDER BY SAP_PART", strSearch];
    NSLog(@"query : %@", qry);

    if(searchStmt == nil) {
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [qry UTF8String] , -1, &searchStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating search view statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    // Loop through the results

    if(sqlite3_step(searchStmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        // Read the data from the result row
        NSLog(@"New row selected");
    }
    else {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while looping search view. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    // Release the compiled statement from memory
    sqlite3_finalize(searchStmt);

    // Set isDetailViewHydrated as YES, so we do not get it again from the database.
    isDetailViewHydrated = YES;
}
```

The method is in it's own class (named Coffee) called from MasterViewController

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    NSLog(@"Text changed %@",searchText); 
    Coffee *coffeObj = [[Coffee alloc] init];
    [coffeObj searchComponents:@"%ZX%"];
}
```

The idea is to change the select statement when searching from a search field..
Does anybody know of a good example doing this ?

Comment: for future projects you should use FMDatabase: https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i was missing the reset

```
sqlite3_reset(searchStmt);
```